# JavaScript create regex programmatically

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I know that I can create a javascript replace like this:

`str = str.replace(/mytarget/g, 'some value');`

that will replace all the occurrences of the literal `mytarget`.
However, I have a big array of words/phrases that I want to use in regex replace, and as regexps are just language elements (they are not wrapped in a string when declaring), I can't find a way to declare regexps programmatically unless I hard-code them. So if I have:

`var arr=['word', 'another', 'hello'];`

I want to produce:

`str = str.replace(/word/g, 'some value');`

`str = str.replace(/another/g, 'some value');`

`str = str.replace(/hello/g, 'some value');`

Please post an example that I can use regexps, as I'll be adding more expressions into the regexps such as whitespace etc. so I NEED it the regexp way. Finally, please don't offer using `eval`, I'm sure there is a better way.

Comment: Why are you using regular expressions? Just do a simple [string replacement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Comment: and the replace pattern simply is a regexp with the reasons I've explained above.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to invoke the RegExp constructor function for that. Example:

```
['word', 'another', 'hello'].forEach(function( word ) {
    var myExp = new RegExp(word, 'g');
    str = str.replace(myExp, 'some value');
});
```

The first argument for the constructor is a string, which literally takes anything you would wrap inbetween `//`. The second paramter is also string, where you can pass modifiers like `g`, `i`, etc.

Answer (score 7):

You can build a RegEx dynamically like this -

```
var word = 'hello';
var re =  new RegExp("\\b" + word + "\\b","g");
```

Remember that you'll need to escape any `\` characters using `\\`

Answer (score 2):

```
for( i in arr )
{
    str = str.replace(new RegExp("\\"+arr[i],"g"), "some value")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are generating the reg-exp on the fly, you can use the RegExp object

```
var a = new RegExp("word")
```